# The two projection maps are different?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm reading [Vistoli's notes](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf), and I came across something on the bottom of page 31, starting with "The reader might find our definition of sheaf pedantic..."

Essentially my problem is the following claim: Let $V \xrightarrow{i} U$ a morphism of schemes and consider the two projections $V \times_{U} V \xrightarrow{p_{i}} V$ for $i=1,2$. If $i$ is not injective, "the two projections will be different".

This seems crazy to me given the symmetry in the construction, can someone please comment?

Comment: ok, I realize that while reading these notes, I should get out of the habit of thinking about just schemes, so maybe this is a problem which arises for some stranger sites. still, even that for me is hard to imagine, so again, what is he getting at.

Comment: Dear martin,  there is no site in sight here ...

Answer (score 3):

Let $k$ be a field.  Take $U=\text {Spec}(k),V=\mathbb A^1_k$ and for $ i:\mathbb A^1_k\to \text {Spec}(k)$ take the structural map.
Then the two projections  $p_i:  \mathbb A^1_k\times_{\text {Spec}(k)} \mathbb A^1_k =\mathbb A^2_k\to \mathbb A^1_k$ are certainly different.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following is meant (and let me generalize this directly to category theory):

Let $i : V \to U$ be a morphism in a category with fiber products. Then the following are equivalent:

- $i$ is a monomorphism
- The projections $p_1,p_2 : V \times_U V \to V$ are equal.
- The diagonal morphism $\Delta : V \to V \times_U V$ is an isomorphism.

The proof is straight forward.

Of course, in concrete categories, "monomorphism" and "morphism with underlying injective map" are completely different concepts. Some authors say "injective sheaf homomorphism" when they actually mean a monomorphism of sheaves. Perhaps this also applies to schemes.